# C++ - How to check if not equal with the & operator

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I am working on a project and we keep track of flags in a single byte.

That byte can be set with a few options. For example:

```
0x00000001 - Person
0x00000002 - Object
0x00000003 - Vehicle
```

Now, when it comes time to check these objects we can do this:

if(flags&0x00000001)
{
    // this is a person
}

The problem is, I want to know how to check and see if it is not a person. Forgive me if this is a simple answer but I have tried if !flags&0x00000001 and it does not check out. I have also tried comparing it to 0 and still, no luck.

Comment: Are you hoping that multiple flags can be set at once? If so, how do you distinguish between (for example) something that is both a person and an object, and something that is simply a vehicle? If not, you should just use equality (`flags==0x00000001`).

Comment: Can I set more than one flag in one byte? How would I do that?

Comment: @PladniusBrooks, Check out a bitwise flags tutorial. `operator|` can apply a flag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You came close. `operator!` has a [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `operator&`, so you need parentheses:

```
if (!(flags & 0x00000001)) {
    //this is not a person
}
```

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you so much. I am working with a bunch of industry pros and this was in their rendering function. So my option without your answer was to either nest everything a level deeper or have a if(flags & 0x00000001) { // do nothing } { else { // do this};

Answer (score 2):

The priority of operator '!' is higher than the operator '&',
so use !(flags&0x1) instead.

PS:  0x3 can't present a Vehicle, but it presents a Person and a Object. Use 0x4 to present a Vehicel.

Comment: Good catch on the 0x3. Was trying to use this as an example. Which numbers are valid at the byte level?

Comment: @PladniusBrooks, Any result of `2^n` is valid for a single bit flag, where `n` is from 0 to `sizeof(type) - 1`. Any number other than those can be the result of combining two or more flags (or zero flags in the case of 0). You might find it easier to define the flags as `2 << 0`, `2 << 1`, `2 << 2`, etc.

Comment: Use `1 << 0`, `1 << 1`, `1 << 2` instead.  To do this, you should look for a book that presents binary numbers and binary arithmetic.  There are all sorts of suggestions on this site, but pick something simple and old-fashioned.  Growing up, I had a Schaum's Outline book that presented the circuitry for 'half-adders' and 'adders'.  Remember, base 2 is the same as base 10, if you cut off all your fingers (with apologies to Tom Lehrer).

Comment: @EricJablow, Oops, those 2s should have been 1s. Thanks for fixing that.